# Processing of items on a queue by a set of workers

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, dataflow

I have a set of workers that I would like to process some data in order the data was added into the queue (buffer block).  After a worker processes the data I would like it to put work item back into the queue.  I wrote the program below but it seems like the workers are not grabbing the data evenly, any suggestions on how to correct this?  Am I using this threading pattern correctly?

e.g. in output I see

> worker 1, work 66, numjobs 32651, sum 2154966
>  worker 0, work 16,
>   numjobs 32637, sum 522192
>  worker 1, work 61, numjobs 32675, sum
>   1993175
>  worker 0, work 72, numjobs 32649, sum 2350728
>  worker
>   1, work 95, numjobs 32688, sum 3105360
>  worker 0, work 86, numjobs
>   32663, sum 2809018
>  worker 1, work 0, numjobs 32649, sum 0
>   <-- this was not expected
>  worker 0, work 98, numjobs 32673, sum
>   3201954
>  worker 1, work 74, numjobs 32649, sum 2416026
>  worker
>   0, work 93, numjobs 32675, sum 3038775
>  worker 1, work 7, numjobs
>   32702, sum 228914
>  worker 0, work 42, numjobs 32642, sum
>   1370964
>  worker 1, work 32, numjobs 32708, sum 1046656
>  worker
>   0, work 99, numjobs 32693, sum 3236607

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace testworkers
    {
        class WorkerArguments
        {
            public int i;

            public int sum;

            public int numjobs;
            public WorkerArguments()
            {
            }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var cancelSignal = new CancellationTokenSource();

                var buffer = new BufferBlock<WorkerArguments>(new DataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 5000, CancellationToken = cancelSignal.Token });

                List<string> splunkProdUsers = new List<string>(new string[] { "worker1", "worker2", "worker3", "worker4" });

                List<Task<int>> consumers = new List<Task<int>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < splunkProdUsers.Count; i++)
                {
                    var consumer = Worker(i, buffer, buffer, cancelSignal.Token);
                    consumers.Add(consumer);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                {
                    buffer.Post(new WorkerArguments { i = j });
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < consumers.Count; i++)
                {
                    consumers[i].Wait(cancelSignal.Token);
                }
            }

            static async Task<int> Worker(int workerId, ISourceBlock<WorkerArguments> source, ITargetBlock<WorkerArguments> target, CancellationToken cancelToken)
            {
                int workProcessed = 0;

                while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync())
                {
                    WorkerArguments workArguments = source.Receive(cancelToken);
                    Console.WriteLine("worker {0}, work {1}, numjobs {2}, sum {3}", workerId, workArguments.i, workArguments.numjobs, workArguments.sum);

                    WorkerArguments nextWorkArguments = new WorkerArguments();
                    nextWorkArguments.i = workArguments.i;
                    nextWorkArguments.sum = workArguments.sum + workArguments.i;
                    nextWorkArguments.numjobs = workArguments.numjobs + 1;

                    target.Post(nextWorkArguments);
                }

                return workProcessed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your workers are all the same, I would recommend using an `ActionBlock<T>`, with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set.

Comment: what is the advantage of using ActionBlock versus what I have currently?

Comment: It has partitioning support built-in. There's no partitioning with `Receive`; whatever worker calls it first is the one that gets the item.